# Is a question asking what an assembly program does off-topic?

Tags: discussion

[How to find the starting value in a for loop in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708949/convert-assembly-code-to-c-for-loop)

It's a question just asking what a particular assembly program does. It feels off topic to me, but none of the close reasons really fits it.

EDIT:
Since I wrote this question, the title has been edited to read "Where is the starting value in this assembly for loop?" Which is more reasonable as stated in BDN's answer below.

Comment: It could be closed for lack of a clear problem statement ("questions about debugging code must contain a problem statement"). Part of that is that questions should have a title that help other users when they're searching problems on Google. In this case; the title doesn't indicate an actual problem, rather a state the user wants to acheive.  That's a smell that the question isn't well formulated.  [This is not uncommon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196744/change-whats-your-programming-question-be-specific-to-what-would-someone-se).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker A simple edit to this one seems to suffice. The user states where his confusion lies, just in the wrong spot where no one is likely to see it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'd still vote to close for the title; If I understood how to frame the question so that it could just be edited, I would; but as someone with no expertise in Assembly, I don't know what words to use.  As such, closing it and letting the OP know why so they  (or someone who knows assembly) can fix the question is best here.  Once they edit it, it'll flow back into the re-open queue.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I clarified your edit; "How do I do this particular thing in this particular loop" is not as useful as "How would I find the starting value in a for loop" (in general).  But, without your edit, I wouldn't have known what to write, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *general* such a question could be construed as "Too Broad", or even "Unclear What you are asking". SO is not a code-conversion service, nor do we accept questions of "What does this giant program do?".

That said, the *specific* question you linked does not seem to be doing that. With a simple edit, his question clearly narrows significantly and I would definitely leave it open. Even if others do not have the same assembly code, an answer could assist them in looking for whatever "trick" there is to determining the starting value.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the user is attempting to grasp the basics of assembly, programming stacks, and CPU registries one could agree that the question's title is off-topic since the question is converting assembly code to C instead of "how do we know the starting value of the function call's parameters".